# /usr/bin/ld cannot find -lbsd

Tags: c, makefile

This is the error I get when I try and make the apue.3e source code from the book Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment.

```
/lib -lapue -pthread -lrt -lbsd
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbsd
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [badexit2] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/john/Documents/apue.3e/threads'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I've looked through similar errors that all seemed to be missing symbolic links to files, but I can't figure out what `-lbsd` is.  When I try to change directory to `/usr/bin/ld` it doesn't exist.  Is `-lbsd` supposed to be in this directory or is it that `ld` just can't find it? I've tried to refrain from posting stupid questions on here, but I can't stand to be stuck on this any longer.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it referring to [libbsd](http://libbsd.freedesktop.org/wiki/)?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I downloaded and made the libbsd file but I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: find / | grep libbsd ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. The first line of your command seems to be incomplete, at best. The linker (which is best invoked via the C compiler) is unable to find a library `libbsd.so` or `libbsd.a` in any of the directories it has been told to look in.  In comments, you say you downloaded and built a  `libbsd` file (which suffix did it have?), but you don't say where you installed it. You'd add a `-L/install/directory/for/libbsd` option to the command line before you specify `-lbsd`. Or try compiling without `-lbsd` to see whether you need it after all.

Comment: Here are a couple more lines before the error. make[1]: Entering directory `/home/john/Documents/apue.3e/threads'
gcc -ansi -I../include -Wall -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE  badexit2.c -o badexit2  -L../lib -lapue -pthread -lrt -lbsd
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbsd
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [badexit2] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/john/Documents/apue.3e/threads'
make: *** [all] Error 1 The problem was I didn't actually install libbsd, I only made it.  I was having a problem with make install and because I didn't have permission and had to do sudo make install.

Answer (score 21):

sudo apt-get install libbsd-dev

Comment: I got the exact same error as the OP, and this solution solved it.

Comment: This also solves the issue on **Fedora 22**.

The command looks like this: `sudo dnf install libbsd-devel` .